# Google earth with and without a proxy

Tags: proxy, google-earth

I'm using google earth on a Linux.  I need to go through a proxy to get to the internet so I start google-earth like this

```
export http_proxy=http://myproxy
google-earth
```

And it works fine.  However, I need need to pull a KML file from a server on an internal network that I cannot access through this proxy.  [This](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#link) example is similar.  When I then open the KML file that says 'pull from this server,' google-earth cannot find the server.  If I start google-earth without setting `http_proxy` I can access the server but not the internet (so I can't pull google-earth data)

From what I've found I can't tell google-earth when to use the proxy selectively.  The only solution I can think of is to forward a port that isn't 80, however I would like to avoid this if possible.

EDIT:
It seems that google-earth [ignores](http://groups.google.com/group/earth-linux/browse_thread/thread/a7823804b5bd81f5/cf6571e4bfa26ae2) the `no_proxy` environmental variable.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
```

Add whatever you need to the no proxy export line.

Disclaimer - I'm not sure if Google Earth respects the no_proxy variable or not.

Comment: it doesn't, how obnoxious.

Comment: Sorry - certain apps need to have something added to their config files in order to do exclusions. I'm not familiar enough with Google Earth to be of much more help.